# Flutter: Nested routing with persistent BottomNavigationBar but without building the unselected pages unnecessarily

Tags: flutter, dart

Throughout the [internet](https://medium.com/coding-with-flutter/flutter-case-study-multiple-navigators-with-bottomnavigationbar-90eb6caa6dbf) and [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54767298/need-a-persistent-same-bottom-navigation-bar-for-all-screens-flutter) I've searched and seen a lot of solutions to the problem of nested navigation with a persistent BottomNavigationBar for Flutter apps. Some of them using *Navigators* with *IndexedStack* or *PageView* and so on and so forth. All of them work just fine **except** that they will unnecessarily build the unselected tabs (sometimes even rebuilding all of them every time you switch tabs) thus making the solution not performatic. I did finally come up with a solution to that – as I was struggling with this problem myself.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The solution is very basic but hopefully you will be able to build upon it and adapt it. It achieves the following:

- nests navigation while persisting the *BottomNavigationBar*
- does not build a tab unless it has been selected
- preserves the navigation state
- preserves the scroll state (of a *ListView*, for example)

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<Widget> _pages;

  List<BottomNavigationBarItem> _items = [
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.home),
      label: "Home",
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.messenger_rounded),
      label: "Messages",
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
      label: "Settings",
    )
  ];

  int _selectedPage;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _selectedPage = 0;

    _pages = [
      MyPage(
        1,
        "Page 01",
        MyKeys.getKeys().elementAt(0),
      ),
      // This avoid the other pages to be built unnecessarily
      SizedBox(),
      SizedBox(),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          return !await Navigator.maybePop(
            MyKeys.getKeys()[_selectedPage].currentState.context,
          );
        },
        child: IndexedStack(
          index: _selectedPage,
          children: _pages,
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: _items,
        currentIndex: _selectedPage,
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            // now check if the chosen page has already been built
            // if it hasn't, then it still is a SizedBox
            if (_pages[index] is SizedBox) {
              if (index == 1) {
                _pages[index] = MyPage(
                  1,
                  "Page 02",
                  MyKeys.getKeys().elementAt(index),
                );
              } else {
                _pages[index] = MyPage(
                  1,
                  "Page 03",
                  MyKeys.getKeys().elementAt(index),
                );
              }
            }

            _selectedPage = index;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyPage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyPage(this.count, this.text, this.navigatorKey);
  final count;
  final text;
  final navigatorKey;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // You'll see that it will only print once
    print("Building $text with count: $count");
    return Navigator(
      key: navigatorKey,
      onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text(this.text),
              ),
              body: Center(
                child: RaisedButton(
                  child: Text(this.count.toString()),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (ctx) => MyCustomPage(count + 1, text)));
                  },
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyCustomPage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyCustomPage(this.count, this.text);
  final count;
  final text;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext parentContext) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(this.text),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 15,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: Card(
                      child: Center(
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          child: Text(this.count.toString() + " pos($index)"),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.of(parentContext).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (ctx) =>
                                    MyCustomPage(count + 1, text)));
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyKeys {
  static final first = GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'page1');
  static final second = GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'page2');
  static final third = GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'page3');

  static List<GlobalKey> getKeys() => [first, second, third];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. The problem I found is that the view doesn't scroll to top when tapping the status bar on iOS. Any idea?

Comment: all code is StatelessWidget, But the page may be need network request data, and then how to fix?

Comment: Doesn't this just delay the problem for a while?  After they've all been clicked then they will all build every time?

Answer (score 0):

###### logic.dart

```
class MainLogic extends GetxController {
  final currentIndex = 0.obs;
  final empty = const SizedBox.shrink();
  late final List<Widget> pages = [HomePage(), empty, empty, empty, empty].obs;
  // main logic
  final constructors = [
    () => HomePage(),
    () => ExplorePage(),
    () => WorldPage(),
    () => MessagePage(),
    () => ProfilePage()
  ].obs;

  void onTap(int value) {
    currentIndex(value);
    if (pages[value] == empty) {
      // main logic
      pages[value] = constructors[value]();
    }
  }
}
```

###### view.dart

```
class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final logic = Get.put(MainLogic());

  MainPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // here
      body: Obx(() => IndexedStack(
            index: logic.currentIndex.value,
            children: logic.pages, //here
          )),
      bottomNavigationBar: Obx( //here
        () => BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: logic.currentIndex.value,
          selectedFontSize: 10.w,
          unselectedFontSize: 10.w,
          selectedItemColor: const Color(0xff84F7D2),
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: _loadImage('ic_tab_home_s'),
              label: '首页',
              activeIcon: _loadImage('ic_tab_home_s'),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: _loadImage('ic_tab_explore_n'),
              label: '发现',
              activeIcon: _loadImage('ic_tab_explore_n'),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: _loadImage('ic_tab_world_n'),
              label: '小世界',
              activeIcon: _loadImage('ic_tab_world_n'),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: _loadImage('ic_tab_message_n'),
              label: '消息',
              activeIcon: _loadImage('ic_tab_message_n'),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: _loadImage('ic_tab_profile_n'),
              label: '我的',
              activeIcon: _loadImage('ic_tab_profile_n'),
            ),
          ],
          onTap: logic.onTap, // here
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _loadImage(imageName) {
    return Image.asset(
      'assets/images/tabs/$imageName.png',
      width: 24.w,
      height: 24.w,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What does 'w' do?  (e.g., 24.w).   That's hard to Google to find the answer.

Comment: 'w' is from a num extension from the package 'flutter_screenutil' which adapts screen and font size. @PeteAlvin