# Flutter 3.10: Keep BottomNavigationBar when push to child screen

Tags: flutter, navigator, bottom-navigation-bar

My problem is simple and complex at the same time, I have 4 screens, **A**,**B**,**C** and **D**, in screen **A** I have a ***TextButton*** that redirects me to Screen2, the situation is that the ***BottomNavigationBar*** is no longer displayed, and in this case is an example, but in case apart from screen A, the others also have a similar situation...how would be the best way to do it, I would not want to install packages if the problem can be solved formally locally. I attach my code below:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreen();
}

class _HomeScreen extends State<HomeScreen> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  final List<Widget> _screens = [
    HomePage(),
    Text('2'),
    Text('3'),
    Text('4'),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBarHomePage(callback: _onTabTapped),
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        title: const Text('Player', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        actions: const [
          SizedBox(
            width: 20,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
            child: Icon(
              Icons.notifications,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: _screens[_currentIndex],
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
    );
  }

  void _onTabTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    });
  }
}
```

```
class BottomNavigationBarHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(int) callback;

  const BottomNavigationBarHomePage({
    super.key,
    required this.callback,
  });

  @override
  State<BottomNavigationBarHomePage> createState() =>
      _BottomNavigationBarHomePageState();
}

class _BottomNavigationBarHomePageState
    extends State<BottomNavigationBarHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomAppBar(
      height: 50,
      elevation: 10,
      shape: const CircularNotchedRectangle(),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.home),
            onPressed: () {
              widget.callback(0);
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
            onPressed: () {
              widget.callback(1);
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.video_camera_front),
            onPressed: () {
              widget.callback(2);
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.person),
            onPressed: () {
              widget.callback(3);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: const Center(
              child: Text(
                'Screen 1',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                  context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Screen2()));
            },
            child: const Text('Go to next screen'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class Screen2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
              child: const Text(
                'Screen 2',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
              ),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: const Text('Go back'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[HomePage -Screen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEMJu.png)
[Screen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vmhj.png)

BottomNavigationBar overlaps when switching screens

Comment: This post can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/66404760/15908730