# How to make BottomNavigationBar persistent and how to make tabs not reload in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, tabs

**SOLVED:** Using CuperinoTabScaffold() with CupertinoTabBar() solved both problems.

Helllo, I have a question about BottomNavigationBar.

Lets say that I have a BottomNavigationBar with 5 tabs looking like this:

Home - Map - Messages - Friends - Settings

And routes:

```
**Home -> 
Map -> 
Messages -> message_screen
Friends -> friend_list -> deletefriend_screen
Settings -> login_screen**
```

The problem is that, i have no idea how to make the BottomNavigationBar not disappear when i push let say friend_list when i am on friends screen.

The second question is, that i want to make Home,Map,Messages,Friends,Settings screens persistent, so when i switch tabs from Home to Map or from `**Map ->Friends-> friend_list -> back to Map**`, map shouldnt reload. But when i go `**Friends -> friend_list -> deletefriend_screen _> Settings -> Friends -> friend_list**` friend_list should reload. Only the first screens, the tabs should be persistent.

Thanks for all help :_)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not quite understand the use case of problem 1, but for the second question, use keepalive:

```
class TestState extends State<Test> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) that solved problem no. 2. The case of problem one is that i want to make BottomNavigationBar persistent, appearing at the bottom of the screen all the time

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are using it. I might need to see your code to understand what is going on. But you can check if this similar post answers your question:

[Flutter: Keep BottomNavigationBar When Push to New Screen with Navigator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49628510/flutter-keep-bottomnavigationbar-when-push-to-new-screen-with-navigator)