# how to navigate using BottomNavigationBar and also with ElevatedButton press in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I am using `BottomNavigationBar` in Flutter, what I wanted is to navigate between  pages by clicking on `BottomNavigationBarItem` normally. And at the same time, navigate to other pages but in the same `BottomNavigationBarItem`. let me explain more by this example that I found [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49628510/flutter-keep-bottomnavigationbar-when-push-to-new-screen-with-navigator)

Saying that my `BottomNavigationBar` has two `BottomNavigationBarItem`: `Call`, and `Message`. And `Call` can navigate (using a `Elevatedbotton` click for example) to `Page1` and `Page2`, while `Message` can navigate (by `Elevatedbotton` click) to `Page3` and `page4`.

**Like this:**

- Call

  -Page1

  -Page2
- Message

  -Page3

  -Page4

[This solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kE8hH.gif) solved 50% of my problem, what I can do now is to navigate from `Call`to `page1` and `page2` always with keeping `BottomNavigationBar` alive, now it still remains the second part, which is clicking on another `BottomNavigationBarItem` in order to navigate to Message

Comment: So you are syaing like call screen can navigate to 2 other screen and message screen can navigate to another 2 screen but bottomnav bar will be there always!! Right?

Comment: Exatly, and  for example when we are in Page1, the bottomNav will be colored at Call (since Page1 is a subtree of Call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try this way.

```
class App extends StatefulWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case 'Site':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SiteScreen());
     
      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home());
    }
  }

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    switch (index) {
      case 1:
        _navigatorKey.currentState!
            .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil("Site", (route) => false);
        break;
      default:
        _navigatorKey.currentState!
            .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil("Home", (route) => false);
    }
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        toolbarHeight: 0,
      ),
      body: Navigator(key: _navigatorKey, onGenerateRoute: generateRoute),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
            label: 'Site',
          ),
         
        ],
        showSelectedLabels: true,
        showUnselectedLabels: false,
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        unselectedItemColor: Color(0xFF9e9e9e),
        iconSize: 20,
        backgroundColor: KBlackColor,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget{
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            child: Column(children: [
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SubHome())
                     },
                    child: Text('Click'),
                )
            ]),
        );
    }
}

class SubHome extends StatelessWidget{
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            child: Column(children: [
                Text('SubHome')
            ]),
        );
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank your for your comment, but your code allow only to navigate between `BottomNavigationBarItem` which are `home` and `site` in your example, I already can do that. Taking your example, what I wanted is to navigate from `home` to another page called `page1` for example by clicking a `ElevatedBottom` and the `BottomNavigationBar` would be still displayed.

Comment: yep. at home page you can navigation to `page1` and `BottomNavigationBar` is show `Home`

Comment: How can I do that, because the given answer still incomplete, can you edit your answer in order to reach that ?

Comment: i had updated. you can check. If u need support anymore you can contact with FB (https://www.facebook.com/linh.nq236)

Comment: That was very helpful, thank you brother and happy coding