# Navigate to a screen without removing Bottom navigation bars

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to use the WillPopScope widget to control the back button. While using Navigator.push on it it navigates to a screen when back button is pressed but the bottom navigation bars get removed. What I want is the bottom navigation bars to still not be removed while using Navigator.push.

```
int pageIndex = 0;

List<Widget> pageList = <Widget>[
  const IsUserWorking(),
  const ReportsScreen(),
  const ProfileScreen(),
];

// bottom navigation bar class

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: pageList[pageIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: CustomLineIndicatorBottomNavbar(
        selectedFontSize: 15,
        unselectedIconSize: 35,
        selectedColor: Colors.blue,
        unSelectedColor: Colors.grey,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        currentIndex: pageIndex,
        selectedIconSize: 35,
        unselectedFontSize: 14,
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            pageIndex = index;
          });
        },
        enableLineIndicator: true,
        lineIndicatorWidth: 3,
        indicatorType: IndicatorType.Top,
        gradient:
            const LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.white, Colors.white]),
        customBottomBarItems: [
          CustomBottomBarItems(
            label: 'Working',
            icon: Icons.assignment_ind_outlined,
          ),
          CustomBottomBarItems(
            label: 'Reports',
            icon: Icons.assessment_outlined,
          ),
          CustomBottomBarItems(
            label: 'Profile',
            icon: Icons.school_outlined,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

// class where im using WillPopScope

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => const ProfileScreen(), 
        ), (route) => false); // removes bottom navy bar.
        return false;
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a persistent bottom navigation bar to achieve this.

There is a great plugin that you can use if you want. [persistent_bottom_nav_Bar](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar)

Comment: I'm already using a package for the bottom navy bars