# Navigating screens from different files (BottomNavigationBar using PageController)

Tags: flutter, dart

My project hierarchy is created similar to a MVC design pattern:

[image]

In the main.dart, I import the `controller.dart` which houses the entire layout (Scaffold, AppBar, BottomNavigationBar) of my app and build the MaterialApp.

`main.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'controller.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MyApp',
      home: const MyHomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}
```

To preserve my pages, I use a `PageView` and `PageController` with `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<MyView>`:

`controller.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  MyHomePageState createState() => MyHomePageState();
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  //Stores the selected index of navbar
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  final PageController _pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0);

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pageController.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  final List<Widget> pages = [
    const View1(),
    const View2(),
    const View3(),
    const View4(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(),
      bottomNavigationBar: _bottomNavBar(_selectedIndex), //My navigation bar,
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: _floatingActionButton, //My FAB
      body: PageView(
        controller: _pageController,
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        children: pages,
      ),
      drawer: const Drawer(),
      extendBody: true,
    );
  }

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
      _pageController.jumpToPage(_selectedIndex);
    });
  }
}
```

[image]

Everything is working as intended, except that I am not able to navigate to a new screen:

`view2.dart`

```
Future<void> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
  DateTime selectedDate = inputDate.toLocal();

  final DateTime? picked = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: selectedDate,
      firstDate: DateTime(2022, 1),
      lastDate: DateTime(
          selectedDate.year, selectedDate.month, selectedDate.day));

  if (picked != null) {
    //Navigate to new screen
    if (!mounted) return;
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const NewView()),
    );
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]

I am pretty sure this isn't the way to do it, but I am not entirely sure how to navigate between screens with my project hierarchy either. My desired output is to push to a new screen while keeping my `BottomNavigationBar`. Much appreciated for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your navigation code is correct, the screen shows like that because your `NewView` is not inside a Scaffold,
to navigate to screen and keep the bottom navigation shown, See the question [#49628510](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49628510/flutter-keep-bottomnavigationbar-when-push-to-new-screen-with-navigator)

Comment: Seems like you're right. Also, using nested navigators solved my issue.