# How to persist bottom navigation bar and App bar using GoRouter?

Tags: flutter, dart, gorouter, flutter-go-router

I'm trying to achieve a page where bottom navigation and app bar are fixed. But when I pressed a button it will go to another page without recreating the app bar and bottom nav bar. For routing I'm using [go_router](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) package.

There is an answer using Navigator [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65666020/7119499). But is there any way to make it using [go_router](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router)?

**Example Page:**

[image: example]

**Example Home Page:**

[image: home page example]

Comment: I assume what you want to achieve is nested navigation. This is a common scenario and can be used as show in this example [here](https://gorouter.dev/nested-navigation).

Comment: I have read that. But in this example it works only when you are navigate in same page. eg: dashboard/family/f2. But I have to push to a new page without rebuilding the app bar and the bottom nav bar. eg: dashboard/family/f2 is the first page. and I have to push dashboard/home. here dashboard holds the appbar and the bottom nav bar.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use `ShellRouter` with `GoRouter` to meet your requirement!

---

##### Router

```
final _rootNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
final _shellNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

final router = GoRouter(
  initialLocation: '/',
  navigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
  routes: [
    ShellRoute(
      navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
      pageBuilder: (context, state, child) {
        print(state.location);
        return NoTransitionPage(
            child: ScaffoldAppAndBottomBar(child: child));
      },
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          parentNavigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
          path: '/home',
          pageBuilder: (context, state) {
            return NoTransitionPage(
              child: Scaffold(
                body: const Center(
                  child: Text("Home"),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: '/',
          parentNavigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
          pageBuilder: (context, state) {
            return const NoTransitionPage(
              child: Scaffold(
                body: Center(child: Text("Initial")),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
```

##### ScaffoldAppAndBottomBar

```
class ScaffoldAppAndBottomBar extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget child;
  ScaffoldAppAndBottomBar({super.key, required this.child});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: const Text(
            "App Bar",
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
        ),
        body: SafeArea(child: child),
        bottomNavigationBar: Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          height: 56,
          width: double.infinity,
          child: const Center(child: Text("Bottom Navigation Bar")),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          onPressed: () {
            context.go('/home');
          },
          child: const Icon(Icons.home),
        ));
  }
}
```

---

#### Output:

##### Initially

[image]

##### After pressing floating button

[image]

---

*Refer detailed code and explaination of bottom NavigationBar using `ShellRoute` and `GoRouter` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74996767/13431819)*

Answer (score 0):

It is still not solved in official release, but you can check this work in progress https://github.com/flutter/packages/pull/2650.
This solves the problem perfectly, hopefully it is merged soon