# I was wondering if we can target a specfic BottomNavigationBar page from a different page in flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation, bottom-navigation-bar

I was looking for a way to target the cart screen from items details page. The carts screen is on one of the tabs on the home screen's BottomNavigationBar.

I am new to flutter and was just trying to see if it is possible or not.

Comment: Reference [how to keep bottomNavBar when push to new screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49628510/flutter-keep-bottomnavigationbar-when-push-to-new-screen-with-navigator)

Comment: Before answering your question, Let's confirm what you want to do, In your app you have bottomNav bar and in second tab you have cart screen. Now you want to navigate user to cart screen from the product details page right?