# Keep BottomNavigationBar When Push to New Screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-pageview, bottom-navigation-bar

I'm using BottomNavigationBar with PageView, how can i keep BottomNavigationBar when go to another screen.

Example:
In BottomNavigatioBar I have 3 screen `A(),B(),C()`. In `A()`, I want to go to `D()` and BottomNavigationBar not losing

Comment: One solution is to use GoRouter's ShellRoute as shown in the example here: https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/main/packages/go_router/example/lib/shell_route.dart

Comment: Please check this I tried this and it works for me.(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49628510/flutter-keep-bottomnavigationbar-when-push-to-new-screen-with-navigator)