# Flutter: iOS NavigationBar Transition

Tags: ios, widget, dart, transition, flutter

Is it possible to replicate this navigation bar transition effect using [Cupertino Widgets](https://flutter.io/widgets/cupertino/)?

[image]

I may not be using the widgets correctly.
And looking at some examples, I have not found any that shows exactly this effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to have a slide transition like `iOS`, you use `CupertinoPageRoute`:

```
CupertinoPageRoute.
Navigator.push(
    context, CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => Screen2()))
```

further you can see [CupertinoPageRoute](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoPageRoute-class.html)

There is also a widget known as [PageView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html) you can check. Maybe that would help

Comment: For me that alone was not enough. I had to embed the first screen into a `CupertinoTabView` to make the navbar transition animation work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is not currently. See [this bug](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9446) - it's something that's being considered by the flutter team but not currently implemented. It's in the Milestone they hope to complete by the 1.0 release (but that could be a while).

That being said, you could do it yourself with a bit of work. You could start with something like the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49415713/flutter-hero-transition-widget-animation-at-the-same-time/49418186#49418186) but animate the AppBar instead of the NavigationBar. Not a particularly pretty solution, but it would work.

Comment: Oh and BTW if you use the CupertinoPageScaffold, CupertinoNavigationBar & CupertinoPageRoute it will get you everything except the cross-fade on the app bar (i.e. push from side, etc).